# Javascript: Show/Hide rows based on current value of drop-down

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I'm working with Javascript and ASP in this scenario.  When this particular page opens, one of my drop-down menus is already populated with a status of "Open" or "Closed" - you can see the value comes from an ID in my recordset.

What I would like to do now is this:  If the status on the page when it first loads is "Closed" and the user decides to change it to "Open" they must re-enter a "Reopen Reason" - so, that would display the header and text box below the drop-down....

Here's what I have tried thus far:  I have created a showHide() function and placed it inside of the select in the drop-down, but it doesn't do anything, so am now stuck.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
  <select name="cboStatus" id="cboStatus" style="width:200px" onchange="showHide();">                           <%
                        RSStatus.MoveFirst
                        If Not RSStatus.EOF Then
                            Do While Not RSStatus.EOF
                                %><option value='<%= RSStatus("ID")%>'
                                <%If RSStatus("ID") = RS("prjStatus") Then Response.Write "selected"%>><%= RSStatus("prjStatus")%></option><%
                                RSStatus.MoveNext
                            Loop
                        End If
                        %>           
                    </select>
```

The HTML that should be produced from the above JS:

```
<tr id="lbReopenReason" style="display:none">
                <td bordercolor="#f0f0e4" bgcolor="#f0f0e4"><h3>Reopen Reason</h3></td>
              </tr>
              <tr id="trReopenReason" style="display:none">
                <td bordercolor="#FFFFFF" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="txtReopenReason" type="text" id="txtReopenReason" value="<%If (RS("reOpenReason")) <> "" Then Response.Write(RS("reOpenReason"))%>" size="100" />
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
    function showHide()
        {
            var cboStatus = document.getElementById("cboStatus");
                  var cboStatusValue = cboStatus.options[cboStatus.selectedIndex].text;
            var lbReopenReason = document.getElementById("lbReopenReason");             var trReopenReason = document.getElementById("trReopenReason");         

            //If the status of the project is Closed at the time of page load, and that status changes, then the user must enter a re-open reason.
            if ( (status == 3) && (cboStatusvalue == 'Open' )
            {
                lbReopenReason.style.display = "";
                trReopenReason.style.display = "";
                }
                  else
{
                lbReopenReason.style.display = "none";
            trReopenReason.style.display = "none";
            }
    }
```

Comment: And what HTML does your asp produce? Can you post a sample?

Comment: Not sure I follow the question- do you mean what happens currently when I change the status to "Open"?  If so, then nothing.  No errors occur, but the resulting text field/header that should appear doesn't.  I've listed above the rows that should come up with that selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have finally resolved this one with the following:

Window onload to populate initial record value:

```
window.onload = findStatus;

    function findStatus()   
    {
        var cboStatus = document.getElementById('cboStatus');
        statusShowHide(cboStatus);      
    }
```

Followed by this Javascript for changing statuses:

```
function statusShowHide(obj)
{   
    var txtStatusFirstLoad = document.getElementById("txtStatusFirstLoad");                  
    var lbReopenReason = document.getElementById("lbReopenReason");
    lbReopenReason.style.display = "none";

    if (txtStatusFirstLoad.value == 3 && obj.value == 1)
    {

        lbReopenReason.style.display = "block";
    }   
}
```

And added this hidden text box to capture initial status value:

```
<input name="txtStatusFirstLoad" id = "txtStatusFirstLoad" type="hidden" value="<%=RS("Status")%>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are two problems here:

1) Your function is called "statusShowHide()", not "showHide()", so that could be the reason it's not getting called.
2) Your onchange attribute is missing its closing quotes after the function call, so that could be it as well.

Give those fixes a shot and see if it works now.

EDIT: A few more suggestions:

In your showHide() method you say:

```
if ( (status == 3) && (cboStatusvalue == 'Open' )
```

when it should be:

```
if ( (cboStatus === 3) && (cboStatusValue === 'Open' ) )
```

Also, instead of the way you're currently getting the value of the  element:

```
var cboStatusValue = cboStatus.options[cboStatus.selectedIndex].text;
```

Try using:

```
var cboStatusValue = cboStatus.value;
```